# When does Qt connection disconnects

Tags: c++, qt5

I have the following scenarios:

```
QAction *sender = new QAction(this);
QAction *reciever = new QAction(this);
auto conn = &connect(sender , &QAction::triggered, reciever ,&QAction::trigger);
```

- Now if I delete `sender` first, `conn` is true and then if I delete
  `reciever`, it is still true.
- But when I delete `reciever` first, `conn` is false and then if I
  delete `sender`, it becomes true(why?).

I thought when you delete receiver or the sender the connection is disconnected.  I don`t understand this behavior.  When is the connection disconnected?

Comment: You're taking the address of the return value. I wouldn't trust that construction.

Comment: Then how do I check if the connection still exists?

Comment: Just use the [`QMetaObject::Connection`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject-connection.html) returned by `Object::connect`.  As pointed out by @Botje your code, as shown, is taking the address of a temporary and has undefined behaviour.

Comment: There is also nothing in the Qt documentation that suggests the connection handle status is updated when a signal disconnects, it only states it can be used to check whether the connection succeeded.

Comment: The returned `QMetaObject::Connection` keeps a pointer to the `QObjectPrivate::Connection`, so you can ask it if the connection is still valid.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed it was an undefined behavior. When I use  returned object by `Object::connect`. It works as expected.